# TestFlight checkpoints not appearing in SDK Debugger (PhoneGap)

Tags: ios, phonegap-plugins, testflight

Using TestFlight with a PhoneGap app, testing on an ipad. In the TestFlight SDK Debugger, I can see `session_start` and `session_end` events, but **NO CHECKPOINTS**. In Xcode debugger, I do see `checkpoints` passed in the console log.

Any idea why checkpoints are not showing up in the SDK Debugger?

EDIT (4/30/12): After using TestFlight for awhile, checkpoints started showing up. Don't know why the discrepancy.

Comment: Have you got the reports now??

Comment: Asked & answered a same question [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366021/only-log-in-debugger-but-no-data-in-report) :)