# Only log in Debugger, but no data in report

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I'm now testing my project with TestFlight, I can see some logs (including checkpoint, session_start, etc) in [SDK Debugger](https://testflightapp.com/dashboard/team/debugger/), but my reports are empty in [Build](https://testflightapp.com/dashboard/builds/). I send email to `support#testflightapp.com`, asked the question on Twitter, and even checked the tweets listed, but still cannot find the solution..I think SO is the only site I can refer to help now..

Have anyone met this issue before & solved now?? And btw, where is the `TFLog`? I cannot find any debug log that I set.

Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT:

Here're two screenshots that will show my issue clearly.

[image]
[image]

You see, I sent feedback, checkpoints (and there're also some session_stard/end logs), but no detail report. :(

---

> SDK Debugger: The TestFlight SDK Debugger lets you see your team's SDK data before it hits our queues. The console also shows orphaned SDK events which can help you confirm you have implemented the SDK correctly.

So I think I implemented the SDK correctly. I tried both SDK v1.0 & v.0.8.3, and I build a new project for testing this service, same result.

How I wish I can offer bounty now!! Please help..

Comment: Btw, I have sent several mails to the official support mail last night, but no reply at the moment...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, I got a reply from Testflight team:

> To be blunt we've been having some stability issues which seem like they're the root cause of your trouble. The team is working as fast as they can to bring you a faster, more stable TestFlight.

unfortunately..

---

And I found the `TFLog` (tested reports from my simulator, but cannot receive reports for my device yet):

1. choose your desired build in `Builds` section;
2. choose `Sessions` in `Reports` section;
3. choose a desired tester, and you'll find some logs like:
   [image]
4. click the blue INFO icon to open a detail dialog:
   [image]
5. and at the top right corner, you'll find a `Events` button, click to open a selection area, then just select the `Log` and you'll get the `TFLog`s.

Comment: Thanks for researching this, I was having the same problem w/ feedback and checkpoints. At least now I know to implement my own stuff for the time being.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, logging appears successful in the console, but nothing on the site is being recieved by myself or our testers.
It's been 24 hours, I've tried the beta and non beta, played around with different compilation options but still no luck.

Comment: @DavidvanDugteren yep, it's not very stable..I think it might depend on the region...not really sure about it. :(

Comment: Has this been fixed yet at all?

Comment: @kermitology I tested a month ago, but still not stable. What a pity. :( Btw, I'm in China.

Comment: It was working when i was uploading through the dashboard. but once i switched to using the upload API. things don't show up in the build anymore...

Comment: @bogardon have you switched to the lasted build? I've not tested the upload API yet, sorry for that.

Answer (score 4):

Just a heads up for anyone experiencing issues with the Testflight SDK not logging events at all.

Double check if you are also using Flurry for Analytics and see if disabling it solves the problem (it did for me). I read somewhere that this is a known issue with the way exception handlers have been implemented on Testflight SDK.